# How to fit an ellipse contour with 4 points?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have 4 coordinate points. Using these 4 points I want to fit an ellipse, but seems like the requirement for cv2.fitellipse() is a minimum of 5 points. Is there any way to get around this and draw a countour with just 4 points?

How does fitellipse draw a contour when cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE is used, which gives only 4 coordinates point.

Comment: use cv::minAreaRect and reinterpret the rotated rectangle as a rotated ellipse.

Comment: Use the minimum area ellipse determined by these four points.

Answer (score 2):

Four points aren't enough to fit an ellipse without ambiguity (don't forget that a general ellipse can have arbitrary rotation). You need at least five to get an exact solution or more to fit in a least square manner. For a more detailed explanation I found [this](https://sarcasticresonance.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-many-points-does-it-take-to-define/).

You can draw the countour itself (without fitting anything) with `drawContours` (or fit e.g. a circle).

So to answer your second question (assuming that I understand it right): It doesn't if there are less than 5 points available, but `FindContours` in combination with `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` returns eventually more depending on the particular detected contour.

See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html). In this C++ example ellipses are only fitted if at least 5 points are available.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the equation for ellipses:

[image]

and the homogenous representation:

[image].

The conic-matrix looks like this:

[image]

you see that it has 6 parameters - one projective degree of freedom, so 5 degree of freedom (if f not equal 0).
Every point on C gives a condition to the parameters a-f. So five points are needed to describe a conic:

[image]

To solve this you need to compute the kernel of the matrix (for five points):

[image]

if you have more then five you need the least square solution:
[image]

and x is the eigenvector from the smallest eigenvalue of [image]